# Cross View Communication

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa, uiwebview

I have a UIWebView on my main window. Can I control that via my second view controller? If so could you give me an example?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes you can. The "how" is a basic Cocoa / application architecture subject you can learn from the introductory documentation from Apple or any number of other web sites.

The gist is that you need to have a reference to the web view's controller (or the web view itself) from the second controller. This could be an outlet or a regular instance variable in the second controller. Then it's a matter of calling `[firstController makeTheWebViewDoSomething];`.

See also [Communicating with Objects](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CocoaFundamentals/CommunicatingWithObjects/CommunicateWithObjects.html%23//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40002974-CH7-SW15).

Answer (score 0):

If you have a "parent" view that owns both the WebView and the other subview from which you want to control.

In the "second view" create a member variable (assign @property and @synthesize, too):

```
  MyUIViewController *parent
```

After creating the "second" view, call:

```
  [[self secondview] setParent:self];
```

Now from the second view, to do something to the WebView, do whatever you want, like:

```
  [[parent webview] goback];
```