# How to access items in the main nib from a document nib?

Tags: cocoa, nswindow, nsdocument

I'm making an NSDocument-based application in which I have an inspector window. This inspector window is part of Pwnshop.nib which is my main nib. I have another nib called 'Document.nib,' which is the document window. I want to be able to change the inspector based on which document window is the active one, sorta like Interface Builder's inspector. The problem is that I want to **access an object in another nib**. Note that there are multiple document windows, but only one inspector window.

Could anyone help me?

Answer (score 0):

This is essentially the same question as [found here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4026372/cross-view-communication/4026488#4026488). The answer is the same, too. You need to read the documentation and learn about [Communicating with Objects](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CocoaFundamentals/CommunicatingWithObjects/CommunicateWithObjects.html%23//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40002974-CH7-SW15) and plan your architecture so that you get get to some universally-reachable controller (eg `[[NSApp delegate] myInspectorController]`) from your NSDocument instances.

Answer (score 0):

I can recommend both [this](http://cocoawithlove.com/2010/06/design-of-every-mac-application.html) and [this](http://cocoawithlove.com/2008/08/application-design-in-appkit.html) article (both from *Cocoa with Love*) for a fundamental lesson in how to structure a Cocoa project. They will answer all of your questions and get you started on a path to building applications the right way.